# Intellij doesn't show methods name in Run Window after published test result

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Intellij doesn't show method names in Run Window after showed Test Result. It only shows number of attempt.

This is what I have in my Intellij.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbsxw.png)

Thanks for help.

This is what I want to have in my Intellij.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72103.png)

Comment: how do you run your tests? with what task, what config? do you use gradle as test runner or IDEA?

Comment: Yes, I have gradle and Windows OS.

Comment: Which runner for tests do you use in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle ? try to change to the opposite one